# ggplot consistent colors between graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am confused as to have ggplot selects colors.  In particular, how do I get the same color across different types of graphs.  Early in my code I define

```
colorscheme = scale_fill_brewer(type="qual",palette = 3)
theme.noframe = theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'transparent'),
                  legend.key=element_rect(fill='transparent'),
                  legend.title=element_blank(),
                  axis.line = element_line(color="black",linetype="solid"),
                  axis.text.x = element_text(color = 'black'), 
                  axis.text.y = element_text(color='black'),
                  axis.title.x = element_text(colour = 'black'),
                  axis.title.y = element_text(colour = 'black'))
```

Later I have the following

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Date, y=value/Divisor, fill=Fill)) + 
  geom_area(position="stack") + xlab("") + theme.noframe + colorscheme +
  scale_x_date( labels=date_format("%Y"),breaks = date.seq  ) +
  ylab(paste("AUM (",LabelScale,")"))
```

which produces

http://rpubs.com/ramachr/154592

Then I call

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Date, y=value/Divisor, color=Fill)) + 
  geom_line() + xlab("") + theme.noframe + colorscheme +
  scale_x_date( labels=date_format("%Y"),breaks = date.seq  ) +
  ylab(paste("AUM (",LabelScale,")"))
```

I then get this

http://rpubs.com/ramachr/154597

The two differences between the calls is 1) geom_line replaces geom_area and 2) color=Fill replaces fill=Fill.

You will notice that for every category, the line colors are different from the area colors.  How can I change either 'ggplot' call to make the color consistent?

Comment: You should have a look at the `scale_color_*` and `scale_fill_*` set of `ggplot` functions.  You will likely be using the `values` parameter in these functions.  This link may be helpful http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Colors_(ggplot2)/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider

```
colorscheme <- list(
 scale_fill_brewer(type="qual",palette = 3),
 scale_color_brewer(type="qual",palette = 3) )
```

Comment: This worked!  However, I can't say why scale_fill is different from scale_color and when I should use which.

Comment: `color` and `fill` are two different aesthetics. `color` mostly applies to line or border colors, fill to the color of areas.